# Get all folders with a given name

Tags: java, recursion, directory

I am searching for a solution to find all folders with the same name in a given directory.

So my folder structure looks like this:

```
                                       Root
                         |                |             |
                     android          windows          ios
                    |       |        |       |       |      | 
                  focus    normal  focus   normal  focus   normal
```

**Note:** There are more folders between the clients and the iconsets, that's why I need recursion.

I want to get a ArrayList with all the pathes of e.g. Normal folders.
Although recursion confuses me a lot all the time I couldnt to it.

This was my first try, which should return **ALL** contained directories in the Root folder (parameter path). The String iconset should define the name of the searched folder afterwards.

```
private static ArrayList<String> getAllIconSetFolders(String path, String iconset) {
        ArrayList<String> pathes = new ArrayList<String>();

        File folder = new File(path);
        File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

        for (File file : listOfFiles) {
            if (file != null && file.isDirectory()) {
                pathes.addAll(getAllIconSetFolders(file.getAbsolutePath(), iconset));
            }
        }
        return pathes;
    }
```

It will return an empty ArrayList in this case.

How can I get all paths for (The normal folders when String iconset = "normal") so my result would look like:

- "Root/android/[...]/normal"
- "Root/windows/[...]/normal"
- "Root/ios/[...]/normal"

Comment: `file` cannot be `null`. Remove that check. Recursively getting all files from a root folder isn't difficult and you should be able to google for it.

Comment: I read on some JVM's it can happen, that's why it is there

Comment: Do you still have the reference? I'd very much like to see it.

Comment: Do you have the permission to read the folder and files?

Comment: I'll have a look. And yeah I guess I could do it to receive all the subfolders, but how can I just add the folder with the given name to my list?
Yes I have all the permissions

Comment: There's an interface called `FileFilter` you can use for that. You pass an implementation to the `listFiles()` method.

Comment: Could you try Breadth First Search 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've just tested the following code and it appears to work correctly:

```
public static List<File> findDirectoriesWithSameName(String name, File root) {
  List<File> result = new ArrayList<>();

  for (File file : root.listFiles()) {
    if (file.isDirectory()) {
      if (file.getName().equals(name)) {
        result.add(file);
      }

      result.addAll(findDirectoriesWithSameName(name, file));
    }
  }

  return result;
}
```

Your original code was almost there, you just omitted the part where you actually add matching directories to your result list.

---

Tested with:

```
C:\tmp\foo
C:\tmp\foo\bar
C:\tmp\foo\baz
C:\tmp\foo\baz\foo
C:\tmp\foo\baz\foo\bar
```

Using

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  List<File> files = findDirectoriesWithSameName("foo", new File("C:\\tmp"));

  for (File f :files) {
    System.out.println(f);
  }    
}
```

Output:

```
C:\tmp\foo
C:\tmp\foo\baz\foo
```

Answer (score 1):

Tested. Works. Need Java 7.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> paths = new ArrayList<String>();
    getAllFolders("/path/to/folder", "normal", paths);
}


private static void getAllFolders(String path, String folderName, List<String> paths) throws Exception {

    Path mainPath = Paths.get(path);
    Iterator<Path> stream = Files.newDirectoryStream(mainPath).iterator();

    while(stream.hasNext()) {
        Path currentPath = stream.next();
        String currentFolderName = currentPath.getFileName().toString();
        if(currentFolderName.equals(folderName)) {
            paths.add(currentPath.toString());
        }
        getAllFolders(currentPath.toString(), folderName, paths);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the directory name to `pathes` otherwise it will always be empty.  Your code should be something like:

```
private static List<String> getAllIconSetFolders(String path, String iconset) 
{
  List<String> pathes = new ArrayList<String>();

  File folder = new File(path);

  for (File file : folder.listFiles()) 
  {
    if (file.isDirectory()) 
    {
      if (file.getName().equals(iconset))
      {
        pathes.add(file.getAbsolutePath());
      }
      else
      {
        pathes.addAll(getAllIconSetFolders(file.getAbsolutePath(), iconset));
      }
    }
  }

  return pathes;
}
```

This assumes the `iconset` is the name of the directory you are looking for and that that directories with that name can exist multiple times in the directory tree.

Answer (score 1):

While searching for directory inside a directory, one elegant way is to use `FileFilter` or for name matching use `FileNameFilter`. On top of it you apply standard recursive ways the complete solution would be:

```
static void test()
{
    File f = new File("e:\\folder");
    List<File> res = new ArrayList<File>();
    search(f, res, "normal");
    System.out.println(res);
    search(f, res, "focus");
    System.out.println(res);
}

static void search(File f, List<File> res, final String search)
{
    if(f.isDirectory())
    {
        File[] result = f.listFiles(new FilenameFilter()
        {
            public boolean accept(File file, String name)
            {
                return file.isDirectory() && name.equals(search);
            }
        });
        if(result != null)
        {
            for(File file : result)
            {
                res.add(file);
            }
        }

        //search further recursively
        File[] allFiles = f.listFiles();
        if(allFiles != null)
        {
            for(File file: allFiles)
            {
                search(file, res, search);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Or you can `extend FileNameFilter` as say `NormalDirFilter` or `FocusDirFilter` where you can hardcode specific folder search name. Use instances of these specific filters while listing file during recursion.

Comment: While this may seem elegant at first, the need to recurse into all folders (regardless of names) makes the filter less helpful in this scenario.

Comment: @DuncanJones included a complete solution, filter is an in-built way for search requirement on finding files, should be preferred IMO.

Comment: I disagree. Compare [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16216242/474189) with yours - in this case mine is more maintainable. However, there are many cases where a filter is appropriate.

Comment: +1, but I think this is too complicated for my needs. I like Duncan's answer becuase it's that simple :)

Answer (score -1):

If you have this structure, could you not do

```
public static List<File> subdirectories(File root, String toFind) {
    List<File> ret = new ArrayList<File>();
    for(File dir : root.listFiles()) {
        File dir2 = new File(dir, toFind);
        if (dir2.isDirectory())
            ret.add(dir2);
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Well, there are more folders in between, which I didn't mention, that's why I need recursion I guess :/